# Create a libreoffice text-based datasource and set settings with java

Tags: java, csv, datasource, libreoffice

I need to create a LibreOffice Text-based-Datasource within Java. My needs are to deliver the user an .csv file with a header row and n-many value rows. This csv File is the datasource to execute a mail merge job. The execution of the mail merge job already works perfectly if I create the datasource manually with the LibreOffice wizard for creating new databases.

In my environment I'm not able to create a database for every user who use the application.

I'm already able to create a new datasource and register it with the follogwing samples of code

```
XSingleServiceFactory service = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSingleServiceFactory.class,
        msf.createInstance("com.sun.star.sdb.DatabaseContext"));

Object datasourceObject = service.createInstance();
XNamingService namingService = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XNamingService.class, service);

XDocumentDataSource datasource = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDocumentDataSource.class, datasourceObject);
XStorable store = (XStorable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XStorable.class, datasource.getDatabaseDocument());

XModel model = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XModel.class, datasource.getDatabaseDocument());       

store.storeAsURL("file:///C:/tmp/1.odb", model.getArgs());

namingService.registerObject("NewDataSourceName", datasource);

XPropertySet datasourceProperties = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, datasource);
csvPath = "C:/tmp/";
datasourceProperties.setPropertyValue("URL", "sdbc:flat:" + csvPath);

store.store();
```

After the execution of this code I have a file named *1.odb* in *C:/tmp/*

Now there is also a "NewDataSourceName" Datasource registered in LibreOffice.
[image: This is the newly created datasource]

The problem is that this datasource doesnt use the .csv file which is located also at *C:/tmp/*.

This is happening because my java program saved the datasoure with the following settings
[image: Settings of the created 1.odb file]

Now I could select the 2nd checkbox (Comma separated value-Dateien (*.csv) and change the fielddelimiter from "**,**" to "**;**" and the *1.odb* would be correctly configured.

I googled alot and found some non-java solutions to set the settings while creating the datasource e.g.

```
::odbSource:Settings:setPropertyValue("Extension"        , "csv")
::odbSource:Settings:setPropertyValue("HeaderLine"       , TRUE)
::odbSource:Settings:setPropertyValue("FieldDelimiter"   , ";")
::odbSource:Settings:setPropertyValue("StringDelimiter"  , '"')
::odbSource:Settings:setPropertyValue("DecimalDelimiter" , ".")
::odbSource:Settings:setPropertyValue("ThousandDelimiter", "")
```

Do someone know how I can set this settings within java?

Sincerly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after multiple times of reading the LibreOffice API I found the right way to do this.

It's so simple I still cant belive that this worked for me.
This are the relevant lines

```
XSingleServiceFactory service = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSingleServiceFactory.class,
                msf.createInstance("com.sun.star.sdb.DatabaseContext"));
Object datasourceObject = service.createInstance();
XDocumentDataSource datasourceDocument =
                UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDocumentDataSource.class, datasourceObject);
XPropertySet datasourceProperties =
                UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, datasourceObject);
XPropertySet datasourceSettings =
                UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class,
                datasourceProperties.getPropertyValue("Settings"));
datasourceSettings.setPropertyValue("Extension", "csv");
datasourceSettings.setPropertyValue("FieldDelimiter", ";");
```

Now my .odb file has the right settings and I'm able to do the mail merge.